# Android imageview gridview

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

Как можно передать картинку из `Imageview` в `Gridview`. Подгружать картинки по одной в `Imageview` при нажатии сохранить, отправлять их в `Gridview`.

Comment: берите картинку не из ImageView, а из того места, откуда вы ее загрузили в ImageView

Comment: Я добавляю фильтры через bitmap. мне нужно брать уже отредактированную картинку. как в инстаграмме короче. Как вариант я думал просто вывести папку с картинками в GridView. ( после сохранения) но вдруг придется делать обратный вывод

Comment: Тогда добавляйте в GridView итоговый Bitmap

Comment: мне бы пример:) гугл говорит так лучше не делать, это плохая практика :)

Comment: Вам нужно всего лишь найти, как сделать GridView с кастомным элементом. Проблема в том, что много Bitmap в памяти держать у вас не получится. Поэтому скорее всего придется все же сохранять изображения в файлы, и загружать\выгружать по мере надобности